# how to refresh view model (knockout js) after changes in database

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am new in knockoutjs please resolve my problem, I just want to refresh my list after changing in database without reloading page. here is my code to display list from apex controller to visualforce page using knockoutjs.

here is my code to display list in vf page from apex controller.

### Apex controller

```
global with sharing class ListView 
{
  @RemoteAction 
  global static list<Employee__c> ListViewMethod()
  {
    list<Employee__c> empRecord;

    empRecord = [select Name,Email__c,Designation__c,Salary__c from Employee__c limit 10];

    system.debug('------'+empRecord);
    return empRecord;
}}
```

### vf page

```
<apex:page controller="ListView">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="mydiv">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Designation</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: emplist">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Email__c"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Designation__c"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Salary__c"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

function MyViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.emplist = ko.observableArray();

    ListView.ListViewMethod(function(result){
                self.emplist(result);

    });

 };

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());

</script>
</apex:page>
```